# What does the assignment operator do for strings

Tags: c

I understand that

```
char* a = "hello";
char* b = "olleh";
strcpy(a,b)
```

will copy the contents of b to a, but what about...

```
char* a = "hello";
char* b = "olleh";
a = b;
```

I was erroneously doing this previously. I was wondering what does the `=` operator do in this case for strings?

Comment: `a` and `b` are *pointers*, not strings. Assignment assigns pointer values.

Comment: Also, since they're pointers to string literals, your first block is undefined behavior. You can't write to string literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strcpy copies the string, by looking at the location of the pointer and copying characters until it copies a null terminator. a and b will point to different strings with the same contents.

a = b is pointer assignment, so a and b will then both point to the SAME memory containing the string "olleh".

Answer (score 0):

a and b will both point to the string `"olleh"`

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    char *a="hello";
    char *b="olleh";

    printf("\n  Before a=b \n");
    printf("a: %d\nb: %d \n\n",a,b);

    a=b;

    printf("\n  After a=b \n");
    printf("a: %d\nb: %d ",a,b);

    return 0;
}
```

The above program is self explanatory. Before the assignment (a=b), a and b are pointing to two different strings, hence they will print two different addresses. But after the assignment (a=b), the contents of a and b will be same, because they point to the same string i.e., "hello".